# How can I use STB library to load image chunks

Tags: parallel-processing, hdr, stb-image

Does anyone know a way to load a HDR image chunk by chunk? I am trying to parallelize a Reinhard Operator algorithm and I have high R/W times. I am trying to reduce that by loading chunks of image at a time, but I can't get my head around it. Is it possible with STB library, or does anyone know another way?

Thanks!

I tried loading the full image at first and then split it, but it does not help much, as the initial reading takes long.